# Select2 options not scrolling with custom scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-select2, mcustomscrollbar

I have got a Div with fixed height and applied custom scroll to it.

Now when I scroll this Div content with mouse wheel, then the select2 options (when kept open) do not scroll along with respective select2 dropdown.

**Here is the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ravk/m2oyLcbn/)  of my problem.**

Click the dropdown to show options and then scroll with mouse wheel keeping options open. The options do not scroll even though dropdown goes up.

Is there any solution for this? Please suggest, thanks!

```js
$('.customize-content').mCustomScrollbar();

$('select').select2({
  minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity
});
```

```html
<div class="customize-content has-toggle">
  <div>

    <select>
      <option>Text 1</option>
      <option>Text 2</option>
      <option>Text 3</option>
      <option>Text 4</option>
    </select>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The html for the dropdown is added outside of the container you are scrolling and overlayed with position absolute.

**Solution**

Use the option `dropdownParent` to add the dropdown within the container:-

```
$('select').select2( {
   minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
   dropdownParent:$('#mCSB_1_container')
});
```

[**Updated Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/m2oyLcbn/1/)

Comment: Thanks! this helps.